# Setting OS X Path variable for Sublime

Tags: macos, path, sublime-text-2, node.js

I'm setting up Sublime to run with NodeJs on my Mac. I get the error below

[image]

However, looking at my Path variable, `/usr/bin/local` is in the Path (I assume these are different?). I'm interested to know why the Node plugin isn't pulling the same `$PATH` as I get in  terminal.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate: [Setting environment variables Mac 10.6](http://superuser.com/questions/182402/setting-environment-variables-mac-10-6) — you need to set a different PATH for GUI.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to applications (Sublime Text in this case) having different PATH than what you get in the Terminal?  None of the links here or elsewhere works on OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 3):

**Quick Workaround:**

Just launch SublimeText2 via your Terminal by typing: `subl`
Then the Plugin has the PATH that is otherwise not really initialized.

Answer (score 2):

For GUI applications in Mountain Lion you need to set the `PATH` variable in **`/etc/launchd.conf`**. You cannot append to the existing `PATH` variable because this file doesn't have access to the environment variable. So you must overwrite the existing PATH variable. Also a restart is required every time you edit `/etc/launchd.conf`.

> setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Source: [Overwatering Blog - Setting the PATH on OS X Mountain Lion](http://overwatering.org/blog/2012/08/setting-path-osx-mountain-lion/)

Comment: I don't have this file.